# Meta descriptions for multilingual site

Tags: html, wordpress, seo, multilingual

I run a multilingual website on Wordpress. If the user's browser runs in Spanish, the Spanish site loads. If the browser has a different language, the English site loads.

**I want to improve the site's meta description so that both languages are included**, but I'm not sure about the best way to do it for SEO.

At first I considered doing it this way, although loading both descriptions together doesn't sound like something Google would like:

```
<meta name="description" content="Spanish version | English version">
```

I also considered this possibility, but read that it's outdated:

```
<meta name="description" lang="es" content="Spanish version"> 
<meta name="description" lang="en" content="English version">
```

Maybe it's best to just write a single meta description and let Google translate it on its own?

**How would you include both meta descriptions** in this case?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been working with Seo Since 2018. The approach you are trying, it's not a good way to deal with it. As you want to rank both language versions. The only thing you can do is, create separate pages for each language version. In that case, your English page will have an English meta description and the Spanish one will have a Spanish meta description.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply! Actually, that sounds like the most streamlined way to deliver both versions of the site, although I think right now it excedes my knowledge and capabilities (not in the future, hopefully). Would it be a decent (temporary) approach something like: if user enters site.com/en -> show English meta description / if user enters site.com/es -> show Spanish meta description? Or do you think it would be sloppy/bad SEO?

Comment: @imthemoisturizer Yes, I meant that, and it wouldn't be temporary. It's a good approch.

Comment: Oh that's great, I misunderstood you, then! Would it be possible to do it with plain HTML or would I need JavaScript?

Comment: Plain Html will be great. Javascript can delay rendering. Also, please accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

no this way is very bad and dont work!
check this google sites:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/managing-multi-regional-sites

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/localized-versions

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://www.example.com/es/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.example.com/" />
```

and this way is **old**!

```
<meta http-equiv="language" content="en">
```